# hot key indication in inno setup

Tags: hotkeys

i am new to inno setup and creating an installer using inno setup.
in this , is there any possibility to indicate hot keys by some means like underlining it ?

for example , while showing license agreement, 'a' is hot key for accepting license and 'd' is for dont accept license.

i want this page as 'a' in accept agreement and 'd' in dont accept... should be underlined.
Is there any chance to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in pages already have this; Windows simply hides the hotkey markers until you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: thank you grawity , is there any way to unhide the hotkeys automatically (without pressing Alt key) whenever license agreement opens ?

Comment: It's a system setting. I'm not sure you can force it for your program on some other PC.

Answer (score 3):

Default Windows UI elements determine hotkeys by marking the hotkey character (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>...</kbd>) with an `&`.

For examble, in your case the UI text will most likely be something like `&Accept` and `&Don't accept`, which would result in the **A** and **D** being shown underlined and the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> being assigned. It doesn't have to be the very first character in a string, so something like `C&ancel` will work as well.

If there are multiple elements with the same hotkey, using the key combination allows you to switch between these elements (similar to how <kbd>Tab</kbd> works).

However, depending on system settings, it's possible to hide those shortcuts by default (got introduced some time in the Windows 98 days I think). They'll only appear once you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> by default, which may be changed under **Ease of Access** -> **Keyboard** in **Control Panel**.